# Why does adding an intermediate view or referring to a sub property break my data binding?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I appear to be misunderstanding something fundamental about Swift / SwiftUI, because I am struggling to understand what is happening in the minimal example below when I introduce an additional view or an additional level indirection.

Here's a simple model consisting of a hierarchy of `ObservableObject`, and some simple views to manipulate it.

```
import SwiftUI

class Model : ObservableObject {
    @Published var sub = SubModel()
}

class SubModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var hue: Double = 0.0
}

struct PickerView: View {
    @Binding var hue: Double
       
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $hue, in: 0...255)
    }
}

struct TextView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(verbatim: String(model.sub.hue))
    }
}

struct PickerWrapperView: View {
    @ObservedObject var sub: SubModel
    
    var body: some View {
        PickerView(hue: $sub.hue)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
            
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //PickerWrapperView(sub: model.sub)
            PickerView(hue: $model.sub.hue)
            
            TextView(model: model)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(model: Model())
    }
}
```

Now, as is, this works as expected: when moving the slider, the text updates to the new value.

However:

- Swapping out the direct use of `PickerView` for `PickerViewWrapper` breaks the data binding: the text no longer updates
- Changing `PickerViewWrapper` to refer to take the instance of Model as input (as opposed to taking the instance of SubModel) fixes the problem (but this is a non starter in my real scenario where I do want to refer to a property of a property of my top model class).

What probably simple concept am I missing here?

Comment: ObservableObjects are not meant to be used nested. Updates don’t propagate to the parent unless you explicitly call objectWillChange.

Comment: @jnpdx I've read about that before and somehow it didn't click that this was the problem! Am I then correct in thinking that the fundamental problem here is that TextView observes model, and model is not notified when model.sub.hue changes?

But then... how does the case without the intermediate view (the state of the code in the question, with PickerWrapperView commented out) even work?

Answer (score 1):

try this approach, using `struct SubModel` instead of **nesting** ObservableObject. With this approach, any change to the `SubModel` will be observed by the `Model` directly, even with intermediate view.

```
class Model : ObservableObject {
    @Published var sub = SubModel()
}

struct SubModel: Hashable {  // <-- here
    var hue: Double = 0.0
}

struct TextView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(model.sub.hue)") // <-- here
    }
}

struct PickerView: View {
    @Binding var hue: Double
       
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $hue, in: 0...255)
    }
}

struct PickerWrapperView: View {
    @Binding var sub: SubModel
//    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        PickerView(hue: $sub.hue)
//        PickerView(hue: $model.sub.hue)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model() // <-- for testing
            
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
               PickerWrapperView(sub: $model.sub) // <-- here with binding
            //   PickerWrapperView(model: model) // <-- here with ObservedObject
            
            // model.sub.hue, will be updated by the SLider
     //       PickerView(hue: $model.sub.hue)
            // the Text in TextView will be updated whenever the model changes
            TextView(model: model)
        }
    }
}
```